# question in an email is it correct to write: any news for new courses

Tags: grammar, writing, email

In an email I want to send to school where I work is this correct to ask 'any news for new courses?'
can I say courses or better to say classes?
is preposition  for correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what information you're trying to get. Are you trying to find out if new courses have been added to the schedule?

Comment: Ringo pretty much answered it, but just to give the most specific answer: the news is **about** new courses.  The news is *for* the people who need the news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***For*** isn't incorrect, but it's also not very specific.

If you're trying to find out if new courses have been added to the schedule, then I would say this:

> Do you have any news as to whether new courses have been added?

Or if you're trying to get news about new courses that definitely exist:

> Do you have any news about the new courses?

It's probably better to use ***courses***, because ***classes*** is a very general term. For example, a class could be an entire course, or it could be a lesson from a single day.